# How to find elements with dynamic names with Quamotion

Tags: webdriver

I'm using Quamotion to test my mobile app.

Until now, I've been able to use expressions like `Find-Element -xpath "//*[@name='some text']"` to find elements on the screen based on the text in those elements. For example, to find the 'Login' button I've been able to use command `Find-Element -xpath "//*[@name='Login']"`.

However, I have some elements which have dynamic texts, such as 'Pick up at [date/time]'.

How can I find an element with a dynamic text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `contains` function in an XPath expression. For example, if you want to find a button which contains the text  'Pick up at', you can use:

`Find-Element -xpath "//*[contains(@name, 'Pick up at']"`

Hope it helps!

Comment: You shouldn't advertise yourself nor ensure your reliability through your job position. Your answer is valid, but disclaimer is unnecessary.